# Error in Android Studio for 9-patch

Tags: android, nine-patch

I do not know what's wrong here, what's the error?

Error:Frame pixels must be either solid or transparent (not intermediate alphas). - Found at pixel #27 along left edge.

Example in xxhdpi

[image]

Comment: Still remains the problem.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [9-patch image error in Android](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4280398/9-patch-image-error-in-android)

Answer (score 3):

The 1 pixel frame (on all sides) used for marking the patches should only contain pixels with black colour and no alpha. Apparently, in your image, the shadow colour that has an alpha component is seen in the 1 pixel frame. You can use the [Draw 9-patch](http://developer.android.com/tools/help/draw9patch.html) tool to create a 9-patch image easily.