# app:mergeDebugResources error in Android Studio after upgrade

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle, aapt

I am getting a error on build/execution of the Android Studio project.

Error:

> :app:mergeDebugResources FAILED Error:Execution failed for task
>   ':app:mergeDebugResources'.
>
> > Some file crunching failed, see logs for details

I have gone through the post on SO and have done the following things to fix it, but I am still not able to get rid of the errors.

1. Clean Project.
2. Invalidate and Restart Android Studio.
3. I have upgraded the Gradle Version from 1.3.0 to 1.5.0.
4. I have also upgraded the buildToolsVersion '23.0.1'.

Few more Gradle traces for reference:

> Information:Gradle tasks [clean, :app:generateDebugSources,
>   :app:generateDebugAndroidTestSources, :app:compileDebugSources,
>   :app:compileDebugAndroidTestSources] :app:clean :app:preBuild
>   UP-TO-DATE :app:preDebugBuild UP-TO-DATE :app:checkDebugManifest
>   :app:preReleaseBuild UP-TO-DATE
>   :app:prepareComAndroidSupportAppcompatV72300Library
>   :app:prepareComAndroidSupportDesign2300Library
>   :app:prepareComAndroidSupportSupportV42300Library
>   :app:prepareComCrashlyticsSdkAndroidAnswers131Library
>   :app:prepareComCrashlyticsSdkAndroidBeta113Library
>   :app:prepareComCrashlyticsSdkAndroidCrashlytics251Library
>   :app:prepareComCrashlyticsSdkAndroidCrashlyticsCore234Library
>   :app:prepareComGithubClansFab155Library
>   :app:prepareComGithubPaolorotoloAppintro320Library
>   :app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesBase780Library
>   :app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesGcm780Library
>   :app:prepareIoFabricSdkAndroidFabric135Library
>   :app:prepareJpWasabeefBlurry101Library :app:prepareDebugDependencies
>   :app:compileDebugAidl :app:compileDebugRenderscript
>   :app:generateDebugBuildConfig :app:generateDebugAssets UP-TO-DATE
>   :app:mergeDebugAssets :app:generateDebugResValues UP-TO-DATE
>   :app:processDebugGoogleServices :app:generateDebugResources
>   :app:mergeDebugResources
>
> AAPT: ERROR: 9-patch image
>   /Users/v/app/src/main/res/drawable-xxxhdpi/btn_small_white_normal.9.png
>   malformed.
>   AAPT:        Found at pixel #21 along top edge. AAPT:
>   /Users/v/Documents/app/src/main/res/drawable-mdpi/ic_send_black_disabled_24dp.png:
>   libpng warning: iCCP: Not recognizing known sRGB profile that has been
>   edited :app:mergeDebugResources FAILED
>
> FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
>
> - What went wrong: Execution failed for task ':app:mergeDebugResources'.
>
>   > Some file crunching failed, see logs for details
> - Try: Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
>
> BUILD FAILED

Comment: Check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/28981972/3967525).

Comment: @Soham: I will let you know after trying it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found the solution to this problem, it might be a temporary fix but it works for now.
This problem is generated because of problem with the 9 patch image.

Look at this line in the traces, its throwing error.

> AAPT: ERROR: 9-patch image
>   /Users/v/app/src/main/res/drawable-xxxhdpi/btn_small_white_normal.9.png
>   malformed. AAPT: Found at pixel #21 along top edge.

I have fixed the error by renaming the asset and removing the .9 from the file name.
The 9 patch file is a malformed asset and Android Studio will not build until its fixed.

You can ask you designer to fix it for you.

Comment: This error is probably thrown because pixel 21 at the top edge of your nine patch file is not (completely) solid or (completely) transparent. This means you have a pixel with an intermediate alpha value at the edge and android does not know what to do (stretch or not) with those pixels.

Answer (score 1):

Had the same issue. Turns out 2 of my image files were corrupted and thus would not crunch. Removed them from Res->Drawable, and voila!

Answer (score 0):

The solution that works for me has been (lucky I copied the project before) ....open the project by "Import project(Eclipse ADT, Gradle,...)
I hope, even if is simple answer, this could help you or someone else.