# Facing issues in resolving the 9-patch images in android studio

Tags: android, android-studio

Hello i am new to the android studio and facing issues while importing the eclipse project to android studio.I have tried cleaning the project and updating the SDK but it not working.The following are the errors i am getting.

Error:ERROR: 9-patch image E:.....\src\main\res\drawable-fr-xhdpi\back_bg.9.png malformed.

Error:Error: com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command 'C:\Users\rahul.kallappa\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\build-tools\21.1.2\aapt.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 42.

Error:Execution failed for task ':...:mergeDebugResources'.

> E:...\src\main\res\drawable-fr-xhdpi\back_bg.9.png: Error: com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command 'C:\Users\rahul.kallappa\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\build-tools\21.1.2\aapt.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 42

[image]

This is the duplicate of another question ,the answers of which are tried and useless . So i created my own question. 
For image with normal names(bg_back.png), we are getting the same error.

Comment: can you show your 9patch?

Comment: I have added the 9patch image.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4280398/9-patch-image-error-in-android

Comment: The picture you have shown **is not** a `9 patch`.

Comment: For image with normal names(bg_back.png), we are getting the same error.

Comment: Hey Can u help with this question your comment i want help for animation the marker https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35554796/rotate-marker-and-move-animation-on-map-like-uber-android